# OpenStack-Ansible: Troubleshooting instance not seeing attached volume

Tags: ansible, openstack, openstack-nova, cinder

I've been working with OpenStack-Ansible 22.0.1 and have successfully brought up a controller node and a compute node with LVM storage that, on the surface, functions. I can now create an instance and boot to an ISO. There is an attached volume that doesn't mention any errors, and the instance boots, but the operating system (Ubuntu 20.04 in this case) tells me:

```
Block proving did not discover any disks. Unfortunately this means that installation will not be possible
```

I've got the syslog (this appears to be the only logging enabled) for both the controller and the compute node connected to PaperTrail and neither mention anything I can recognize as an error or failure. openstack volume list appears to show that the volume is functional as well:

```
# openstack volume list
+--------------------------------------+------+--------+------+---------------------------------+
| ID                                   | Name | Status | Size | Attached to                     |
+--------------------------------------+------+--------+------+---------------------------------+
| 8bfa1a84-9409-4db6-b669-aca43ce4d38e |      | in-use |   20 | Attached to Ubuntu on /dev/vda  |
+--------------------------------------+------+--------+------+---------------------------------+
```

I'm sure there is a proper way to troubleshoot this issue, but I am not having any luck figuring it out and haven't found another channel to tap to gain this knowledge. Any insight into the correct troubleshooting process for an error like this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is kind of interesting. I created a Ubuntu Desktop image so I could go into a live environment. lsblk shows the disk. /dev/vda, as existing and having a few partitions, /dev/vda1 mounted at /cdrom, and /dev/vda3 mounted at /var/crash. /dev/vda is the 20G volume as is expected, but its almost like its just shoving the image into the new volume and booting from it rather than from the ISO.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is that OpenStack is specifically designed to run on pre-built images, not perform installations from ISOs as I had previously expected. There are a bunch of pre-built images here: https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/obtain-images.html

It was alluded to that if you did a "rescue" mode that you could boot from an ISO and perform an install, but I haven't gotten far enough in my test to confirm or deny.